Why is my Binary PSO feature selection showing no progress?
I have written a Python script as follows:

A data-file file of path '/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset.csv'
(a) dataset file is 6.62 GB in size
(b) has 1079134 rows excluding the header row
(c) has 1029 columns
Divide the rows into 25 chunks each of size chunk_size
Read a chunk chunk of size chunk_size from file
Remove first three columns from the left hand side and create a dataframe df
If the left-most column of any row in df contains anything other than characters {A,B,C}, remove that row from df
Take left most column of df as the target column y
Map the target values into intergers as {A:0,B:1,C:2}
Take rest of the columns of df as features X
Apply particle swarm optimizer and a very fast classifier (choose yourself) to find best feature-columns
Dispose the chunk and free memory
go to step#3 until all n chunks are not done processing
Use voting to select best features
Save the selected features to file '/content/drive/MyDrive/feature_selection_output.txt'

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pyswarms as ps
from datetime import datetime as dt
import gc

# File path
file = '/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset.csv'
output_file = '/content/drive/MyDrive/feature_selection_output.txt'

# Constants
chunk_size = 1079134 // 25

# Initialize variables
selected_features = []

# Function to map target values
def map_target_values(val):
    mapping = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}
    return mapping.get(val, -1)

# Function to apply particle swarm optimization
def f_per_particle(m, alpha, X, y, total_features, classifier):
    if np.count_nonzero(m) == 0:
        X_subset = X
    else:
        X_subset = X[:, m == 1]
    
    scores = cross_val_score(classifier, X_subset, y, cv=3)
    P = scores.mean()
    
    j = (alpha * (1.0 - P) + (1.0 - alpha) * (1 - (X_subset.shape[1] / total_features)))
    return j

def f(x, alpha, X, y, classifier):
    n_particles = x.shape[0]
    total_features = X.shape[1]
    j = [f_per_particle(x[i], alpha, X, y, total_features, classifier) for i in range(n_particles)]
    return np.array(j)

# Read and process file in chunks
for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=chunk_size):
    # Remove the first three columns
    df = chunk.iloc[:, 3:]
    
    # Filter rows based on the left-most column values
    df = df[df.iloc[:, 0].isin(['A', 'B', 'C'])]
    
    # Map target column and extract features
    y = df.iloc[:, 0].map(map_target_values).values
    X = df.iloc[:, 1:].values
    
    # Handle missing values by imputing with zero
    imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value=0)
    X = imputer.fit_transform(X)
    
    # Scale the data
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
    
    # Define classifier with increased max_iter
    classifier = LogisticRegression(max_iter=5000)
    
    # Initialize swarm for PSO
    options = {'c1': 1, 'c2': 1, 'w': 0.5, 'k': 100, 'p': 20}
    dimensions = X.shape[1]
    
    optimizer = ps.discrete.BinaryPSO(n_particles=100, dimensions=dimensions, options=options)
    
    # Perform optimization
    cost, pos = optimizer.optimize(f, iters=100, alpha=0.9, X=X, y=y, classifier=classifier)
    
    # Record selected features
    selected_features.append(pos)
    
    # Free memory
    del df, X, y, optimizer
    gc.collect()

# Use voting to select best features
final_selected_features = np.sum(selected_features, axis=0)
selected_feature_indices = np.where(final_selected_features > (len(selected_features) / 2))[0]

# Save selected features to file
with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
    for idx in selected_feature_indices:
        f.write(f"{idx}\n")

print(f"Selected features have been saved to {output_file}")


I ran this script

on Google Colab (free plan, 28 GB HDD and 12 GB RAM)
on GeForce GTX 780

In both cases, the script shows no progress.
Output:
2024-07-06 19:24:47,269 - pyswarms.discrete.binary - INFO - Optimize for 100 iters with {'c1': 1, 'c2': 1, 'w': 0.5, 'k': 100, 'p': 20}
pyswarms.discrete.binary:   0%|          |0/100


PySwarms contains no GPU acceleration I can find, so your assertion that you are running “on GTX780” (and I guess implying that you are running on a Colab GPU accelerated instance) is false. So given that your (very large) problem is running on single threaded native Python and numpy, have you considered the possibility that you see no progress because it is extremely slow?

@talonmies, Yes, I finally concluded the same. Then I tried to use CuPy but failed to install.
